# PostgreSQL - Error column reference "id" is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql

I've aliased everything, but can't seem to get this query working without the

> error column reference \"id\" is ambiguous"

It seems to work if i remove one of the joins, but i'm just confused as to why it won't work with two?

```
create function influence.person_info(user_id integer)
  returns setof influence.person_object as
$$
    declare
    obj influence.person_object;
    begin
        select t1.email as a_email, t2.organisation_url as a_org, t3.first_name as a_first, t3.last_name as a_last into obj
        from influence_private.person_account as t1
        inner join influence_private.organisation_account as t2 on (t1.organisation_id = t2.id)
        inner join influence.person as t3 on (t1.person_id = t3.id)
        where id = $1;
        return next obj;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;
```

Any pointers?

Comment: just some hints - this function returns just one row. Then it should be defined `RETURNS influence.person_object` and `RETURN` should be used instead `RETURN NEXT`. RETURNS SETOF can be significantly slower than RETURNS composite. More, probably rows estimation will be significantly wrong in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **where** clause you will need to explicitly state which **id** you are referring to.

Comment: That has solved it. Much appreciated. Sometimes a 2nd pair of eyes is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your query:

```
select t1.email as a_email, ...
from influence_private.person_account as t1
join influence_private.organisation_account as t2 
  on (t1.organisation_id = t2.id)   -- here
join influence.person as t3 
  on (t1.person_id = t3.id)         -- here
```

Both your tables (`influence_private` and `influence`) have column named `id`. Postgresql doesn't know which one you want to use so you have to use full name like `t2.id`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your query is `t2` and `t3` both tables have a column called `id`. In the `Where` clause `id` is ambigous because it doesn't know what `id` you are refering (`t2` or `t3`) specify it and it will work properly.

Example fix:

```
create function influence.person_info(user_id integer)
  returns setof influence.person_object as
$$
    declare
    obj influence.person_object;
    begin
        select t1.email as a_email, t2.organisation_url as a_org, t3.first_name as a_first, t3.last_name as a_last into obj
        from influence_private.person_account as t1
        inner join influence_private.organisation_account as t2 on (t1.organisation_id = t2.id)
        inner join influence.person as t3 on (t1.person_id = t3.id)
        where t1.id = $1;
        return next obj;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;
```